# How can I speed up my solution to this self-describing number puzzle?

Tags: python, puzzle

I came across [this puzzle](https://twitter.com/centerofmath/status/253197327479762944/photo/1/large) from centerofmath.org via Twitter:

> There is a ten-digit number where the leftmost digit is also the number of zeros in the number, the second leftmost digit is the number of ones and so forth until the last digit (or rightmost digit) is the number of nines in that number. **What is this number and is it unique?**

I wrote a program in Python to solve the puzzle:

```
def yielder(exponent):
     i = 10**exponent
     while i < (10**(exponent+1))-1:
          yield i
          i += 1

def is_solution(num):
     l = list(num)
     #l.reverse()
     is_sol = True
     for i, e in enumerate(l):
          if int(e) != l.count(str(i)):
               is_sol = False
               break
     return is_sol

if __name__=="__main__":
     import sys
     ofile = open('solution.txt', 'w')
     j = int(sys.argv[1])
     print("checking between {0} and {1}".format(10**j, (10**(j+1))-1))
     ofile.write("Solutions between {0} and {1}:\n".format(10**j, (10**(j+1))-1))
     for x in yielder(j):
          if is_solution(str(x)):
              ofile.write('\t{0}\n'.format(x))
              print("solution is {0}".format(x))
     ofile.close()
```

And the solution I got is `6210001000`

But the problem is it took several hours to solve. I want to know if there is some technique I could have used to make it faster

BTW these are the numbers between 10 9,999,999,999 that are solutions

```
Solutions between 10 and 99:
Solutions between 100 and 999:
Solutions between 1000 and 9999:
    1210
    2020
Solutions between 10000 and 99999:
    21200
Solutions between 100000 and 999999:
Solutions between 1000000 and 9999999:
    3211000
Solutions between 10000000 and 99999999:
    42101000
Solutions between 100000000 and 999999999:
    521001000
Solutions between 1000000000 and 9999999999:
    6210001000
```

Comment: Your program appears to be working correctly, and you're asking for advice on how to improve it - that sounds like you should be asking this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: this won't give you any speedup, but i thought i'd point out it is pointless for you to do the `l = list(num)` in your worker function because `num` is a string which is also iterable and has `count`.

Comment: @RanjithR, you could run the loop `for x in yielder(j)` in a couple of threads, using python multi-threading, since the iterations are not dependent on each other.

Comment: and 9000000000 is not a solution? also 8100000000, and so on...

Comment: @andrean 9000000000 can not be a solution because it has 1 nine, and a 0 in the corresponding "9's" position.

Comment: @wim dammit you're right, sorry :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker Oh. You're right. Can I move this question there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much faster if you construct the number other than search for it.

```
def to_the_number(n):
    digits=list(map(int,n))
    assert(len(digits))==10
    done = False
    while not done:
        done = True
        for i in range(10):
            if digits[i]!=digits.count(i):
                digits[i]=digits.count(i)
                print(digits)
                done = False
    return ''.join(map(str, digits))
```

And start from any number:

```
>>> to_the_number('1234567890')
[1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 8, 9, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[7, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[7, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[7, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[6, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[6, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[6, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
'6210001000'
```

Comment: And the second part of the puzzle? (Is it unique?)

Comment: This gives a solution but how can I say it is unique

Comment: @RanjithR you marked this as the answer too soon. This solution doesn't work all the time; it has the potential to get stuck in an infinite loop. Change the `10`s to `5`s and start from `'12345'` to see. @Kabie 's solution doesn't indicate if the puzzle is unsolvable, and it doesn't indicate if the solution is unique. You should unmark it as an answer; it's misleading to say it is.

Comment: While I too find this answer very interesting, approach-wise, it will not complete for numbers other than 10, even if you modify the code to remove the assertion and change `range(10)` to `range(len(digits))`.  For example, try it with 4 and you get 1 answer. Try it with 5 and it never terminates.

Comment: I would have loved to see this go on, but this community closed the question too soon. So I thought of killing it.

Comment: This is a simple(and bugged) implementation which trying to simulate how one solve the puzzle by hand.
I think the right way to solve it is mathematic. It is easy to prove that number of zeros(the first digit) can not less than 6, and can not be 7, 8 or 9. When 6 is locked down the rest is obvious. This small program is not smart enough to prove that. The point is that to find and test all the possible solutions will cost lots of time eventually. So a straightforward way could be faster.

Comment: This fails on 3-digit numbers. Also, the function should count how many digits are there and not have that hard-coded..

Answer (score 3):

You can cut out massive amounts of number checks by using a bit more logic.  For example, you know that the sum of the individual digits *must* be 10, otherwise the number has too many digits, so try taking advantage of that.

You could, for example, change your yielder to only generate numbers for which the condition `sum(int(n) for n in num) == len(num)` is satisfied, then you don't need to check with an expensive loop on numbers which you already know can't make sense.

Comment: Why must the sum of the digits be **10**? a self-descriptive number can be `110` for example, or `1210`..

Comment: @vsync Read the problem description carefully.  It starts like this:  "*There is a **ten-digit number** where...*".  More generally, the sum of the digits must equal the length of the number.  1210 is a good example, but 110 is not correct (there are two 1's).

Comment: Sorry, mixed this with self-descriptive number, which is something else. Keep up the good work Mr. Wim!