# How to generate a 'N' digit Self describing number

Tags: java, c#, python, random

How can I construct a `N` **digit number** which follows certain condition as follows.....

A) 1st digit equals to the numbers of 0's,

B) 2ond digit equals to the numbers of 1's,

C) 3rd digit equals to the numbers of 2's,

D) 4th equals number of 4's till Nth digit equals to the numbers of (N-1)'s.

I know that such number is called as **Self-describing** number

eg- `6210001000` is the 10 digit number of such kind.

But I need to know the `C#` or `Java` program to generate such number.

There is a bit similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704061/how-can-i-speed-up-my-solution-to-this-self-describing-number-puzzle) which contain `python` program to find such number but I am not much familiar with python` and judging from that question and its comments, the programs given there faces serious performance issue.

**Edit:** this is python version of constructing such number

```
def to_the_number(n):
digits=list(map(int,n))
assert(len(digits))==10
done = False
while not done:
    done = True
    for i in range(10):
        if digits[i]!=digits.count(i):
            digits[i]=digits.count(i)
            print(digits)
            done = False
return ''.join(map(str, digits))
```

which only works for N=10

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, it's a mathematical question

Comment: Also, `2100010006` seems wrong - there are definitely more than 2 0s. There are also no 5s, and there isn't 6 9s. Edit: looking again, it seems like the definition is wrong: the 10th digit represents the number of 0s, not the first.

Comment: @Rob , Corrected the number 2100010006 to 6210001000

Comment: This is a programming question but there is no code to debug or look at hence it is off topic. You need to provide some kind of code that has an issue with it. The site isn't for people to write code for you or teach you how to write basic code, rather it's a resource for helping people who know how to code.

Comment: @krw12572 *But I need to know the C# or Java program to generate such number* - since you have the python code can you not just cross correlate? Whilst I appreciate the effort that you put into editing and writing the question it still remains off topic as you are effectively asking someone to write code for you without presenting your own attempt in `C#` or `Java`

Comment: I am undeleting this question since I've found the code I was looking for. I am also posting the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following code generates 10 digit self describing number

```
class NumberConstructor
{
    uint inds_sum = 0;
    uint inds_val = 0;
    private uint noOfDigits;
    private uint inds_max;
    uint[] inds = new uint[10];
    uint[] nums = new uint[10];
    private uint[] digs = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    public void SelfDesc()
    {
        noOfDigits = 10;

        inds_max = noOfDigits - 1;

        GenerateSelfDescribingNumber(noOfDigits);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private void GenerateSelfDescribingNumber(uint i)
    {
        uint j;

        if (i != 0)
        {
            var diff_sum = noOfDigits - inds_sum;
            var upper_min = inds_sum != 0 ? diff_sum : inds_max;

            j = i - 1;

            uint lower;
            uint upper;

            if (j != 0)
            {
                lower = 0;
                upper = (noOfDigits - inds_val)/j;
            }
            else
            {
                lower = diff_sum;
                upper = diff_sum;
            }

            if (upper < upper_min)
                upper_min = upper;

            for (inds[j] = lower; inds[j] <= upper_min; inds[j]++)
            {
                if (inds[j] < i || nums[inds[j]] < inds[inds[j]])
                {
                    nums[inds[j]]++;
                    inds_sum += inds[j];
                    inds_val += inds[j]*j;
                    uint k;

                    for (k = inds_max; k > j && inds[k] - nums[k] <= i; k--) ;

                    if (k == j)
                        GenerateSelfDescribingNumber(i - 1);

                    inds_val -= inds[j]*j;
                    inds_sum -= inds[j];
                    nums[inds[j]]--;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (j = 0; j < noOfDigits; j++)
                Console.Write(digs[inds[j]]);

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I got some help from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/41tdzy/20160120_challenge_250_intermediate/)